# How to create custom preview windows like that available for particle systems

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

[enter image description here][Unity Particle System Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0JMz.png)

I'm looking into creating custom modules in the unity editor and I thought about creating a custom floating window like that available for particle systems. I figured it would be useful for monitoring live variables for debugging purposes. Does anyone know how I go about creating something like this?

See attached image for reference.

I looked into object previews but it isn't quite the same thing.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-EditorWindows.html

Comment: There is literally the [**SOURCE CODE**](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Modules/ParticleSystemEditor/ParticleSystemWindow.cs) available for that one ;) And here also for the referenced [`ParticleEffectUI`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Modules/ParticleSystemEditor/ParticleEffectUI.cs)